# Set tab active based on condition causes error in display of other tabs angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using a tab component in my project. Initially it works fine. However, when I set active for second tab based on some condition and when I click on the third tab, the second tab is not removing active and the third tab gets active and is displayed in the same page below the second tab content. How do I fix this issue?

When the third tab gets clicked, I want the second tab to remove active showing only the third tab and its content. Plunker for component I am using is in my comment

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/afhLA8wHw9LRnzwwTT3M?p=preview

Comment: I dont see any problem in the Plunker provided. Is it updated?